# how to resolve "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:8081"

Tags: javascript, node.js, client-server

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response){
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

response.end('hello suneha\n');
}).listen(8081);
console.log('server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');
```

ERROR caught on the browser while running the node js program [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OX0j.png)

Comment: First of all you are running at 8080 instead of 8081 port. So try http://127.0.0.1:8080/ it should work.

Comment: So, when you run the node program, any errors? or just the `Server running at ...` message? Any errors in **node** when you try to access the page? Are you running this on windows? Did windows popup a dialog regarding allowing node to act as a server? Did you allow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem you are using wrong name `respponse` it should be `response.`

```
http.createServer(function (request, response){
```

Comment: it was typing mistake while posting , sorry for this . i have edited the question. 8081 port is only under listen

Comment: It is working fine. I have tried replacing `respponse` to `response` in my local machine  on line `http.createServer(function (request, response){`  and it is working fine.

Comment: `Am a beginner in node js` - in what way is that relevant

Comment: sorry again, it was typing mistake while posting.

Comment: @SunehaBanuJ I have replicated same in my local. Just running `node test.js` assuming test.js has all the above code. It is running fine on all the browsers.

Comment: key to solving this would be to know what is output on the nodejs console

Comment: Yes @SunehaBanuJ What is in the terminal from which you are running the node js server?

Comment: Great. Please select the answer if it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

may be some other process was using 8081 port.
I have tried with different port number and it is working fine[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr4ZL.png)